# Canvas.drawLines: strange glitch leading to spontaneous gradient line drawing

Tags: android, canvas, lines, antialiasing

I've got a `canvas.drawLines()` and a `Paint` with antialiasing set. If I turn it off, the effect goes away

What's happenning: for some reason, if the last point of `toDraw` is on the screen, the lines are drawn as shown on the left screenshot. If it's dragged outside the screen, the lines are drawn solid as shown on the right one - and that's how it should be
Checked `toDraw` in debugger - the last point has valid coordinates

[image: Antialias glitch]

Paint properties setting:

```
paint.setColor(0xFF000000);
paint.setStrokeWidth(1.2f);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
```

Drawing code:

```
canvas.translate(dx, dy); //dx and dy are the only things different for the screenshots
float[] toDraw = ...;
canvas.drawLines (toDraw, paint);
```

Any ideas why this is happenning?

Comment: `Is there a way to avoid that?` Yes, by **not using** AntiAliasing: `paint.setAntiAlias(false);`. But I really prefer the antialiased version.

Comment: Me too, so I need a way to avoid that without turning antialiasing off

Comment: Pure conjecture here, but do you have a repeating pattern, where certain values of dx and dy give better results than others? If so, then perhaps you can clamp dx and dy to multiples of a certain base?

Comment: You can't remove the antialiasing effect from the antialiasing effect. So, the question is: do you want it ot not?

Comment: By the effect I meant this glitch, not antialiasing

Comment: What you call "gradient" is the effect of the anti-aliasing blur.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like antialiasing setting is highly affected by small objects: the last two points in the array were very close to each other - dx,dy ~ 1E-4

Possible solutions (checked on Android 4.0.4):
- To delete one of those close points
- To call `myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)`, where myView is the View containing your Canvas
- To disable antialiasing

Comment: What you call "gradient" is the effect of the anti-aliasing blur. So, the only viable solution seems to me the last one.

Comment: But this blur is somewhy caused by a line with dimensions ~1E-4.  When it's on the screen, all the lines drawn by this `drawLines()` call are blurred, when it's not - all the lines are drawn antialiased without the blur (as shown on the right screenshot). So I removed that tiny line and there is no blur now. Also, all the solutions listed work on my device

Comment: `1E-4` means 10^-4. It is a very small number, very close to zero. And pixels are sored as tuples of integer values, not floating point. So, I guess you have some glitches due to approximations.

Comment: Maybe, antialiasing is set to match the smallest objects - that could explain why the blur covered the most of the lines' areas instead of their edges only